# Unable to Connect to MailStore for Bounce Processing

Tags: civimail, cron-job

Tested on Wordpress 4.7.3 and Joomla

CiviCRM 4.7.16

We've set up a domain for all Civi-related mail processing for our CiviCRM clients for whom we provide site management. For one account we are unable to get the bounce processing job to connect to the mail account. We have no issues using the mail account to send and receive from both webmail and setup in a mail client. All ports are open and functioning. We've tried both IMAP, POP and SSL, TLS. Fails every single time.

Any ideas?

Here is the entry from the ConfigandLog directory:

```
Mar 16 17:14:22  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array (
  [message] => Could not connect to MailStore for lemoyne_bounces@mailprocessing.org
    Error message:
    An error occured while sending or receiving mail.
    Failed to connect to the server: mailprocessing.org:143.
  [code] =>  
)

Mar 16 17:14:22  [info] $backTrace = #0
/home3/pnmiinfo/public_html/lemoyne/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(331):
CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /home3/pnmiinfo/public_html/lemoyne/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Mail/EmailProcessor.php(177):
CRM_Core_Error::fatal("Could not connect to MailStore for
lemoyne_bounces@mailprocessing.org<p>Error...")
#2 /home3/pnmiinfo/public_html/lemoyne/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Mail/EmailProcessor.php(58):
CRM_Utils_Mail_EmailProcessor::_process(TRUE,
Object(CRM_Core_DAO_MailSettings))
#3 /home3/pnmiinfo/public_html/lemoyne/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/v3/Job.php(361):
CRM_Utils_Mail_EmailProcessor::processBounces()
#4 /home3/pnmiinfo/public_html/lemoyne/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php(89):
civicrm_api3_job_fetch_bounces((Array:1))
#5 /home3/pnmiinfo/public_html/lemoyne/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(169):
Civi\API\Provider\MagicFunctionProvider->invoke((Array:9))
#6 /home3/pnmiinfo/public_html/lemoyne/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(100):
Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest((Array:7))
#7 /home3/pnmiinfo/public_html/lemoyne/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php(23):
Civi\API\Kernel->runSafe("Job", "fetch_bounces", (Array:1), NULL)
#8 /home3/pnmiinfo/public_html/lemoyne/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/JobManager.php(134):
civicrm_api("Job", "fetch_bounces", (Array:1))
#9 /home3/pnmiinfo/public_html/lemoyne/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/JobManager.php(113):
CRM_Core_JobManager->executeJob(Object(CRM_Core_ScheduledJob))
#10 /home3/pnmiinfo/public_html/lemoyne/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Page/Job.php(149):
CRM_Core_JobManager->executeJobById("3")
#11 /home3/pnmiinfo/public_html/lemoyne/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php(172):
CRM_Admin_Page_Job->browse(NULL, NULL)
#12 /home3/pnmiinfo/public_html/lemoyne/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Page/Job.php(136):
CRM_Core_Page_Basic->run()
#13 /home3/pnmiinfo/public_html/lemoyne/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(310):
CRM_Admin_Page_Job->run((Array:3), NULL)
#14 /home3/pnmiinfo/public_html/lemoyne/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84):
CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#15 /home3/pnmiinfo/public_html/lemoyne/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52):
CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#16 /home3/pnmiinfo/public_html/lemoyne/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1227):
CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#17 [internal function](): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
#18 /home3/pnmiinfo/public_html/lemoyne/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(298):
call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:1))
#19 /home3/pnmiinfo/public_html/lemoyne/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(323):
WP_Hook->apply_filters("", (Array:1))
#20 /home3/pnmiinfo/public_html/lemoyne/wp-includes/plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#21 /home3/pnmiinfo/public_html/lemoyne/wp-admin/admin.php(222): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
#22 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

A common issue is to have missing php extensions, are you sure your php has imap extension enabled?

(the command to install it depends on what OS or distrib you use).

Comment: That's a good theory, except that I tested the new email address on a site that has bounce processing and SMTP working with an existing email address and encountered the same errors. Plus, I can use the new email address as IMAP in Thunderbird and it works fine.